# Trying to swipe cardViews between two recyclerViews

Tags: java, android, arrays

Im currently working in android studio and im trying to use onswipe to allow the user to move cardviews between 2 arrays
basically the way it would work is you swipe a cardview in one recyclerview it shows up in the other
ive setup a basic implementation but its not working

ive looked for at a ton of tutorials and tried to get gtp to help me
this is all the code related to the recyclerviews within this project

````
 private PitchAdapter pitchAdapter2;
 private BenchAdapter benchAdapter1;
 private BenchAdapter benchAdapter2;

 ArrayList<Player> playing = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Player> playing2 = new ArrayList<>();

 ArrayList<Player> benched1 = new ArrayList<>();

 ArrayList<Player> benched2 = new ArrayList<>();

     // Set up RecyclerViews In the OnCreate
     RecyclerView field1RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.field1);
     RecyclerView field2RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.field2);
     RecyclerView bench1RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bench1);
     RecyclerView bench2RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bench2);

     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
     LinearLayoutManager layoutManager4 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

     bench1RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
     bench2RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
     field1RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager3);
     field2RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager4);


     pitchAdapter1 = new PitchAdapter(this, playing);
     pitchAdapter2 = new PitchAdapter(this, playing2);
     benchAdapter1 = new BenchAdapter(this, benched1);
     benchAdapter2 = new BenchAdapter(this, benched2);


     field1RecyclerView.setAdapter(pitchAdapter1);
     field2RecyclerView.setAdapter(pitchAdapter2);
     bench1RecyclerView.setAdapter(benchAdapter1);
     bench2RecyclerView.setAdapter(benchAdapter2);

     ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper1 = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
     android.util.Log.d("STRING",  "CHECKINGATTACH");
     itemTouchHelper1.attachToRecyclerView(bench1RecyclerView);



ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
     @Override
     public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
         if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
             android.util.Log.d("TAG", "CHECK");
             int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
             Player player = benchAdapter1.getPlayerAtPosition(position);

             // Update bench adapter and field adapter
             benchAdapter1.removePlayerAtPosition(position);
             pitchAdapter1.addPlayer(player);

             // Update underlying data structures
             benched1.remove(player);
             playing.add(player);

         }
     }
 };```


package com.example.teamcreatorv2.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.teamcreatorv2.Items.Player;
import com.example.teamcreatorv2.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BenchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BenchAdapter.benchViewHolder> {


 Context context;

 ArrayList<Player> players;



 public BenchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
     this.context = context;
     this.players = players;
 }



 public Player getPlayerAtPosition(int position) {
     if (position >= 0 && position < players.size()) {
         return players.get(position);
     }
     return null;
 }

 // Method to remove a player at a specific position
 public void removePlayerAtPosition(int position) {
     if (position >= 0 && position < players.size()) {
         players.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
     }
 }


     @NonNull
     @Override
     public BenchAdapter.benchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
     int viewType){
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pitch_cards, parent, false);
         return new BenchAdapter.benchViewHolder(view);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull BenchAdapter.benchViewHolder holder,int position){
         holder.Name.setText(players.get(position).getPlayerName());
         holder.Num.setText(players.get(position).getPlayerNumber());
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount () {
         return players.size();
     }



     public static class benchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         TextView Num;
         TextView Name;

         public benchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
             super(itemView);
             Num = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Num);
             Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
         }

     }
 }


package com.example.teamcreatorv2.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.teamcreatorv2.Items.Player;
import com.example.teamcreatorv2.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PitchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PitchAdapter.pitchViewHolder> {

 Context context;

 ArrayList<Player> players;



 public PitchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players){
     this.context = context;
     this.players = players;
 }
 // ...

     // Method to get a player at a specific position
     public Player getPlayerAtPosition(int position) {
         if (position >= 0 && position < players.size()) {
             return players.get(position);
         }
         return null;
     }


     // Method to remove a player at a specific position
     public void removePlayerAtPosition(int position) {
         if (position >= 0 && position < players.size()) {
             players.remove(position);
             notifyItemRemoved(position);
         }
     }

      public void addPlayer(Player player) {
          players.add(player);
         notifyItemInserted(players.size() - 1);
 }


     // ...



 @NonNull
 @Override
 public PitchAdapter.pitchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pitch_cards, parent, false);
     return new PitchAdapter.pitchViewHolder(view);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PitchAdapter.pitchViewHolder holder, int position) {
     Player player = players.get(position);
     holder.Name.setText(players.get(position).getPlayerName());
     holder.Num.setText(players.get(position).getPlayerNumber());
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return players.size();
 }



 public static class pitchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     TextView Num;
     TextView Name;
     public pitchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
         super(itemView);
         Num = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Num);
         Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
     }

 }
}


Im almost certain im trying to be too blunt about the whole thing and theres a much cleaner way to make this work this is my first android studio project so im still trying to figure all this out
````

Comment: Can you share the removePlayerAtPosition & addPlayer methods or the full adapter implementation?

Comment: Yes ive added both adapters to the code block

Comment: Ok, your code looks fine to me. Now can you explain what's the issue? is the card not swiping? is it removing from the first recyclerview but not showing in the other? is it not removing at all from the recyclerview ? are you getting some kind on exception... etc
You need to explain further the problem you are not facing.

Comment: The card wont swipe pretty much is all
when i do swipe I get those shadow stretch indicators at the border of the recyclerView
Ive done a logCat check and the itemtouchhelper isnt even being triggered